# Is the ambiguity of a regular tree grammar decidable?

Tags: formal-languages, computability, formal-grammars, ambiguity, tree-grammars

Is there an algorithm which decides whether a regular tree grammar $G$ is ambiguous, i.e. there exists a tree $t\in L(G)$ which can be parsed by the grammar in more than one ways, using only leftmost derivations?

Is there a proof available about the decidability, or a cite to a paper which proposes such an algorithm?

Comment: What do you mean by "regular tree grammar"?

Comment: @vonbrand, [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_tree_grammar)

Comment: A cursory look makes this expressible by a LISP-like language (use `()` to enclose each tree), so the corresponding context free language is `LR(0)`. My answer would be that the flattened grammar is `LR(0)` exactly when the tree grammar is unambiguous. But I might be overlooking something...

Comment: @vonbrand nice idea. what exactly do you mean by enclosing each tree with brackets? Each root node of a right hand side of each production? Each node which is not a leave?

Answer (score 3):

Start by considering regular *string* grammars. We can determine whether one such grammar $G$ is ambiguous by constructing the intersection of the grammar with itself, with a direct product construction. The nonterminals are pairs $(A,B)$ of nonterminals from the original string grammar $G$. The new grammar of course also derives the original language $L(G)$, but the new grammar has a nonterminal $(A,B)$ with $A\neq B$ in a succesful derivation, iff $G$ is ambiguous. It is decidable whether any given nonterminal occurs in a succesful derivation, so ambiguity is decidable for regular grammars.

The same is true, mutatis mutandis, for regular tree grammars.

Comment: The grammar $S \to aS \mid aaS \mid a$ is ambiguous, yet I doubt you'll find the pair you are looking for in the product. I think the basic idea can work; you need to find disagreeing pairs of productions, though.

Comment: Thanks @Raphael. Indeed, it is about finding disagreeing pairs of productions, while the letters generated match. However, I was not thinking of grammars, but based my intuition on finite state automata. Because regular tree grammars are somewhat like automata, except the "control" moves to parallel branches. I will rephrase this later.

Comment: @HendrikJan please keep in mind, that the _letters_ do have an arity, where only nullary letters are used as leaves, all others with a higher arity are inner nodes of a tree.